# Undeclared identifier viewForZoomingInScrollView

Tags: undeclared-identifier

this is my protocol

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HypnosisterView.h"

@interface HypnosisterAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
HypnosisterView *view;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

this is implementation of delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

CGRect screenRect = [[self window]bounds];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];

[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:1.0];
[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:5.0];

[scrollView setDelegate:self];

[[self window]addSubview:scrollView];

CGRect bigRect = screenRect;
view = [[HypnosisterView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect];
[scrollView addSubview:view];
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return view;
}

[scrollView setContentSize:bigRect.size];


BOOL success = [view becomeFirstResponder];
if (success) {
    NSLog(@"HypnosisView became the first responder");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Couldn't become first responder");
}


self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

even after confirming protocol giving error **Undeclared identifier viewForZoomingInScrollView.**
i have copy this method from apple documentation and also cross verified by doing jump to definition of that delegate.
it shows undeclared thats why is not appearing on autosuggestion too.
please help me out.
thank.

Answer (score 1):

You may kick yourself when you realise the error. I implemented your code and got the same error. Despite the fact that you're overriding a method and therefore shouldn't need to declare it in your .h file...I decided to do this anyway. Still, undeclared.

It was at this point I realised that you'd written the method for 'viewForZoomingInScrollView' within your 
-(BOOL)application:applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. So I removed it from there placed it above and problem solved.

tldr: remove the viewForZoomingInScrollView method from

-(BOOL)application:applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.